# Error in menu design xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was just applying menu to my app.

For that i written following code in xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item 
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
          android:title="Search" />

</menu>
```

I started getting error on line:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
              android:title="Search" />
```

Error Statements:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Element type "item" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".   activity_login.xml  /MessageReader/res/layout   line 6  Android XML Format Problem
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   activity_login.xml  /MessageReader/res/layout   line 6  Android AAPT Problem
```

Edit:(Full Code)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item 
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="Search" />

</menu>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/msngr"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.38"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_username"
                 />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" 
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/view_password"
               />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/link_to_register" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: The error message says that your error is in a layout file (activity_login.xml), not a menu. Or did you put your menu file in the `/res/layout` folder?

Comment: @Dalmas but when i double click on that error, it brings me to this line of code,,,and error has also started comming after i added menus

Comment: your menu xml file is fine. check if it's in proper folder `res/menu`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i dont have any menu.xml i added it in login, see my edit

Comment: YOu can't add it your main file...you have to need to add it in menu.xml file

Comment: @NavatKayAahe. This is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your menu XML in separate file (menu.xml) and put that file in /res/menu folder of your project.

And after that you ca use it in

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your menu XML in separate file (i.e. `menu.xml`) and put that file in `/res/menu` folder of your project.

**EDIT**

> but latter how can i have that menu on my login page?

You do not add menu to layout. You add it to i.e. Activity. And you do this in the code that way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but latter how can i have that menu on my login page?